# Как правильно залить проект в GitHub с помощью GitHub Desktop?

Tags: github

Скажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Пытаюсь залить проект через GitHub Desktop, нажимаю создать новый репозиторий, выбираю папку, а у меня появляется только файл `.gitattribute`. Не судите, если вопрос глупый.

Comment: Ещё появляется папка `.git`, но она скрытая. Больше ничего и не будет — вы создали новый, пустой репозиторий.

Answer (score 6):

Для работы с GitHub Desktop на официальном сайте GitHub есть документация (на английском). Для изучения специфики работы данного приложения, ознакомьтесь с ней [пройдя по ссылке.](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/getting-started-with-github-desktop/)

С учетом того, что GitHub Desktop у вас уже установлен и с интерфейсом вы ознакомились, далее просто необходимо авторизироватся и добавить необходимый репозиторий.

Как добавить? Все просто. Есть два способа:

1. Через интерфейс сайта GitHub. Находясь в нужном репозитории, нажимаем кнопку склонировать репозиторий в GitHub Desktop (*Save [имя_репозитория] to your computer and use it in GitHub Desktop*). После этого вам будет предложено выбрать папку, в которую склонируется проект. Далее он автоматически скачается и запустится в GitHub Desktop.
2. Склонировать напрямую из GitHub Desktop. Для этого нужно нажать на значок плюса в левом верхнем углу интерфейса и перейти на вкладку *Clone*. Выбираем в списке нужный нам репозиторий и нажимаем *Clone*. После этого будет предложено выбрать папку, в которую склонируется проект.

Теперь, независимо от выбранного способа клонирования, с репозиторием можно работать.

Comment: Нашел инструкцию на русском, на всякий. [Смотрите пройдя по ссылке.](https://o7planning.org/ru/10283/using-github-with-github-desktop)

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался, просто ночью сидел, не дал название изменениям что внёс. На следующий день на свежую голову решил вопрос.